# Document root appending in url rewriting

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite url from http://www.example.com/books/PHP/wrox to http://www.example.com/manuals/opensource/wrox

I have added the following rule

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^books/PHP/(.*)$    manuals/opensource/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The URL redirection appends my document root as

http://www.example.com/home/projects/www/publications/devel/manuals/opensource/wrox

My document root is /home/projects/www/publications/devel/
Thanks In advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the definition of the Directory statement you're Rewrite rule is in, according to [this question on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/93195/mod-rewrite-adding-documentroot-to-url).

Comment: I tried adding rule in directory with document root and it gives me 500 error

Comment: Can you post the complete snippet from your httpd.conf? So, the whole directory statement?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
RewriteRule ^books/PHP/(.*)$    manuals/opensource/$1 [R=301,L]
```

To

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/books/PHP/(.*)$ $1/manuals/opensource/$2 [R,L]
```