# .htaccess mod_rewrites appends document root to URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In essence possibly quite similar to that question: [Document root appending in url rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187605/document-root-appending-in-url-rewriting)

The possible solutions linked in that question did not work.

**Problem**: I want to use .htaccess mod_rewrite 
in order to:

- rewrite `http://<IP>/tutorials` to read from file `/var/www/html/tutorials.html` instead of listing the `/var/www/html/tutorials/` directory if it exists.
- main issue is that whatever I try, it seems to append the directory root to the URL as in, `http://<IP>/tutorials` becomes `http://<IP>/var/www/html/tutorials.html` for example.

My `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

My `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My `/var/www/html/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
<lots of misguided attempts went there>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57416723/htaccess-file-to-remove-html-from-url-not-working/57418257#57418257

Comment: it's getting there thanks to that answer, I'm going to disable the auto-trailing slash on directory that should help as well.

Comment: feel free to comment here if you need help.

Comment: Thanks @BijayRegmi I have posted my answer below, feel free to recommend further improvements. I haven't actually solved my problem with the document root. Instead I worked around by using the %{REQUEST_URI} instead of the first element of the RewriteRule regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Bijay Regmi, I managed to reach the behavior I wanted. It took a combination of things to get it right:

```
# Removing the indexes
Options -Indexes

# Removing the auto-slashing for directories
DirectorySlash off

RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash

# Show file instead of folder if file exist
# URL: /docs/tutorial
# SERVE: /docs/tutorials.html
# FINAL_URL: /docs/tutorial
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1.html [NC,L]

# Prettify URLs
# URL: /docs/tutorial/tuto
# SERVE: /docs/tutorials/tuto.html
# FINAL_URL: /docs/tutorial/tuto
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1.html [NC,L]

# Folder contain another sub-site
# URL: /docs/api
# SERVE: /docs/api/index.html
# FINAL_URL: /docs/api/index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/docs\/api$
RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/index.html [R,NC,L]

# Show index file of folder when folder requested
# URL /get_started
# SERVE: /get_started/index.html
# FINAL_URL /get_started
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1/index.html [NC,L]
```